# Need help making this Slideshow create a loop so it timesout and then times back in

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am currently working on creating a slideshow using jquery and what I'm having trouble with is making a reoccurring loop that will time out the slide show for a certain amount of time ie. 10mins and then have it reappear and run the slideshow again and then continue this forever. I can't seem to get anything to work.

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animations.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rDI2jF4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DS5peX5.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

So as I stated I am able to get the slideshow up and running but need to know where I can find information on what I need for timing the slideshow out for a set amount of time and then bring it back in to run the slideshow again.

Comment: I put your logic into a runnable snippet.  I mean it seems to work...

Comment: @taplar I know it works fine thats not what I needed help on, I need to know how I can have the slideshow disappear based on an amount of time and reappear. Once it reappears it runs the slide show again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the whole thing to disappear after x time and reappear after y time? 
 Doesn't setTimeout work for this?

```
.hidden { display: none; }

function myInterval(showInterval , hideInterval) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('slideshow');
    var targetInterval;

    if ((" " + elem.className + " " ).indexOf( " " + hidden + " " ) > -1) {
        elem.classList.remove('hidden');
        targetInterval = showInterval;
    } else {
        elem.classList.add('hidden');
        targetInterval = hideInterval;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){ myInterval(showInterval , hideInterval) }, targetInterval);
};

myInterval(showInterval , hideInterval);
// showInterval = how long the animation will be visible
// hideInterval = how long the animation will be hidden

// this will hide it at the start, and show it after the 'hide' interval
// to make it show from the start, add the 'hidden' class on the Element from the start
```

Or you could use setInterval instead, if you want it to be the same period of showing/hiding:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('slideshow').classList.toggle('hidden');
}, x); // x is the time for how long the animation will be visible/hidden
```

Comment: is there a variable in there for the code to be set with a certain timer for how long it shows and one for how long it is hidden before it resets?

Comment: myInterval(10000 , 5000) - it will show for 10 seconds, will hide for 5 second, then it will show for 10 seconds, will hide for 5 seconds, and so on. or the second, with setinterval, replacing x with 3000 for example, will show for 3 seconds, will hide for 3 seconds, and repeat

Comment: You my friend are my hero....lol me and my buddy couldn't figure this out  for hours yesterday! Thank you again and +1

Comment: Glad it helped. ^^ Best of luck!

Comment: Please mark as accepted answer if it worked properly, in order to set this aside, and potentially guide future readers. Thx :)

Comment: I have implemented the code and now it is not showing the images at all, is there a reason for this or is it possibly my div with the id slideshow? Do I need to put all images under on id?